# Fix file permissions on a Mac

Tags: macos, permissions, chmod

I'm having a weird behaviour on my mac. I got some files from another computer, and for some reason the system can't identify the user related to some permissions. Here is a pic of what I get on the finder permission manager —is in Spanish, but I'm pretty sure that in English would be very similar—

[image: this]

Basically, what it says, is:

```
obtaining…      writing and reading
admin           writing and reading
munchausen (Me) writing and reading
wheel           writing and reading
everyone        writing and reading
```

So is like it can't find the name of a user, which makes sense, because this files had permissions for an user that doesn't exist in this computer.

How can I clean this permissions? From the folder, I tried with:

```
sudo chmod -R 754 .
```

It gave proper permissions, but didn't solved the problem of the `obtaining…` thing.

Any idea?

Comment: did you try chwon? the issue with obtaining… is with user

Comment: Hhhmnop. I know how to use chmod, but no experience with chown. Any advice on this command?

Comment: this should help. http://osxdaily.com/2013/04/23/change-file-ownership-mac-os-x/ other simple ways too